# How can methods be called when browser's refresh button is clicked?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want some methods to be called every time the page is being loaded. `protected override void OnInitialized()` works well on first load and when returning from another component, but not when the browser's refresh button is hit.
I tried `protected override void OnParametersSet()` and the other methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481713/blazor-and-browser-page-refresh) and also `protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)` but nothing works.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> > I want some methods to be called every time the page is being loaded.

Use `OnInitialized{async}`

> > when the browser's refresh button is hit

Is that what you really mean?  That's when the SPA restarts.  If you only want your "methods" to run once you can put them in `App.razor` on the `OnInitialized{async}`.  Depending on how long these take, you could add load time to you application.

Note - without an understanding of what these "methods" do, this is just a generic answer.

#### Update

Here's my test page.  Standard WASM hosted Project, the Index page.

The time gets updated every `<F5>` on the browser window i.e. `TestMe` gets run.

Do you have debugging configuration problems?

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div>@message</div>

@code {

    protected string message;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TestMe();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected void TestMe()
    {
        message = $"Loaded at: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work, maybe my description was unclear. I start my app and navigate to a component. The component contains `OnInitialized()` and therefore my methods calculate values A with the default values from input boxes. Now the user can enter new values, what results in values B. Until here, everything works fine, but now it could happen, that the user uses the browser's refresh button. This leads to the default values in the input boxes but not in a recalculation, because `OnInitialized()` is not triggered and also `OnInitialisedAsync()`, `OnParametersSet()`...

Comment: When a browser refresh occurs this restarts the Application for the user - <F5> also does this.  `OnInitialized` and the rest all get called, but with default data - there's no state preservation.  Are you expecting the user entered numbers to be preserved?  Otherwise please lost some example code illustrating your problem.

Comment: In Visual Studio simply create a new Blazor WebAssembly App and add `protected override void OnInitialized() { TestMethod(); } private void TestMethod() { var test = 1; }` to the code block of Counter.razor. Set a break point at `var test = 1;` and run the app. When you click the Counter button in the nav menu the app breaks but not when you now press <F5>. But that is, what I want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Very interesting, the time gets updated but the app breaks at `message = $"Loaded at...` only on app start and e. g. when returning from Counter. It does not break when I click <F5>. Can you confirm this. So, probably (I cannot test this at the moment) I do not have the described problem in my real app but only thought so, because my break point did not work.